# LINQ to XML aggregates and group by

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm Attemping to do a SUM and a Group By in LINQ to XML. I'm also using LINQPad 4 to test my linq out. For some reason rate = g.Sum(taxRate) is giving me a FormatException error. I'm pretty sure this LINQ query could be cleared up as well. I know that "Taxrate" can be an empty string, I wish to just default 0 or ignore any empties. Any suggestions?

```
var tax = from taxRate in TaxRates.Descendants("Code")
          where 
          taxRate.Attribute("taxrate") != null 
          &&
          Int32.Parse(taxRate.Attribute("taxyear").Value) == TaxYear
          group taxRate by taxRate.Attribute("taxunitid").Value into g
          select new
          {
              ID = g.Key,
              rate = g.Sum(taxRate => Decimal.Parse(taxRate.Attribute("taxrate").Value))
          };
taxRatesByTaxUnit.Dump();
```

Here's some sample xml.

```
<Code taxyear="2005" tusfundid="12" cycleid="575" taxunitid="198674" taxrate=".214000000"/>
<Code taxyear="2005" tusfundid="13" cycleid="575" taxunitid="198674" taxrate=".004"/>
<Code taxyear="2005" tusfundid="13" cycleid="575" taxunitid="198674" taxrate=""/>
<Code taxyear="2005" tusfundid="13" cycleid="575" taxunitid="100000" taxrate=""/>
```

I expect to get back of

```
taxunit id: 198674: taxrate = .218  
taxunit id: 100000: taxrate = .000
```

Comment: Show the XML. We can't help you without it.

Comment: First thing: stop using `Decimal.Parse` and `Int32.Parse` - use the custom conversions provided by LINQ to XML. Your code will be shorter, and it'll be more reliable as it'll use the expected XML format.

Comment: Your second `Code` doesn't have a useful `taxrate` value - what did you expect it to do?

Comment: @Jon Skeet First off; honor to have you comment. Second off; I'm just randomly throwing stuff into the wind now. To answer the third question; all I want it to do is sum the taxrates and group them by the taxunitid.

So; for this example,  taxrate would stay at .214... if I had another code with the same taxunitid shouldn't it add it up?

Comment: @xphill64x: So you're saying that `taxrate=""` should be equivalent to `taxrate="0"`? If you're responsible for the XML generation, I'd change it to make the `taxrate` attribute *always* have a value, for sanity's sake.

Comment: @JonSkeet If only life was that easy... (Def not an option)

Comment: So *do* you want to treat it as a "0"? If there's a tax unit which *only* has one entry, and that has a taxrate of `""` do you want that tax unit to be present in the results or not? You really need to carefully define your expected results.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Did not think of that situation. I "guess" if there is a taxunitid with 0 taxrates we should include them in result.Based on the xml I have "0" and "" are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, given the "tax rate of an empty string should be treated as 0", I would probably break that up into a separate method. It's simpler than trying to do it inline. Then I'd use explicit conversions everywhere.

So something like:

```
private decimal GetTaxRate(XElement code)
{
    XAttribute rateAttribute = code.Attribute("taxRate");
    return (string) rateAttribute == "" ? 0m : (decimal) rateAttribute;
}

...

var query = from code in TaxRates.Descendants("Code")
            where (int?) code.Attribute("taxyear") == TaxYear
               && code.Attribute("taxRate") != null
            group code by (string) code.Attribute("taxunitid") into g
            select new {
                ID = g.Key,
                rate = g.Sum(code => GetTaxRate(code))
            };
query.Dump();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; is there no "default attribute if empty/invalid in linq"? Also; what is "ParseTaxRate(code))?

Comment: @xphill64x: `ParseTaxRate` was a typo for the `GetTaxRate` method I'd defined. As for "default attribute if empty" - no, typically you would apply a default for a *missing* attribute, and that's fairly easy. A *specified* attribute with an empty string value is normally meaningful.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I did not know you can specify methods inside of linq like that. (Though, hindsight don't see why I couldn't)